# React google maps add marker with user location

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have integrate google maps into my website and i want add a marker with user location. First file is Map.js and second MapContainer.js. In MapContainer.js
in this file I have all the data for map rendering, circle, zoom, API and map dimensions
Sorry for the code format, but this is the second time I'm writing on this community

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    GoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    Marker,
    Circle
} from "react-google-maps";




const Map = props => {

    return (

        < GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={props.zoom}
            defaultCenter={props.center}


        >

            {
                props.places.map(place => {
                    return (

                        < Fragment key={place.id} >

                            {place.circle && <Circle
                                defaultCenter={{
                                    lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                                    lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)
                                }}
                                radius={place.circle.radius}
                                options={place.circle.options}
                            />
                            }

                        </Fragment>
                    );
                })
            }
        </GoogleMap >
    );
}

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

// position = {{ lat: 45.764288, lng: 21.209806 }}
```

~

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Map from "./Map";


const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Zona Verde",
        latitude: "45.752814",
        longitude: "21.229137"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Zona Galbena",
        latitude: "45.752814",
        longitude: "21.229137"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Zona Rosie",
        latitude: "45.752814",
        longitude: "21.229137"
    },


];


data[0].circle = {
    radius: 10000,
    options: {
        strokeColor: "green",
        fillOpacity: "0.1",
        fillColor: "green"
    }
};
data[1].circle = {
    radius: 20000,
    options: {
        strokeColor: "yellow",
        fillColor: "yellow",
        fillOpacity: "0.1"

    }
};
data[2].circle = {
    radius: 30000,
    options: {
        strokeColor: "red",
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: "0.1"
    }
};

export default function MapContainer() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Map

                style={{ borderRadius: "25px" }}
                center={{ lat: 45.764288, lng: 21.209806 }}
                zoom={10}
                places={data}
                googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_6NDZYcE5HDyU9onLOGrsLN2kgW0QIn4"
                loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />

        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put Marker component inside GoogleMap the same way like you add circles.

```
const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={props.zoom} defaultCenter={props.center}>
      <Marker position={{ lat: 45.764288, lng: 21.209806 }} />
      /* circles */
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

Also you can add another prop to Map component and pass marker with other props.

```
<Map marker={ props.marker } style={ /* etc. */ }/>

//inside GogleMap
<Marker position={ props.marker } />
```

**UPDATE**

Use my previous answer but also add new state to MapContainer which will be passed to Map. This state will be user position taken from Geolocalization API.

```
const Map = (props) => {
    return (
         <GoogleMap defaultZoom={props.zoom} defaultCenter={props.center}>
             <Marker position={{ lat: 45.764288, lng: 21.209806 }} />
             /* circles */
          </GoogleMap>
     );
};
```

```
export default function MapContainer() {
    const [ marker, setMarker ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            ( location ) => setMarker({ 
               let: location.coords.latitude,
               lng: location.coords.longitude
            })
        )
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Map
                marker={ marker }
                style={{ borderRadius: "25px" }}
                /* etc. */
            />

        </div>
    );
}
```

Then you can pass marker as prop to Map.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to add coordinates manually. I want it to be a marker for the user's position. To be more specific: When a user uses the site, a marker should be displayed on the map for his position, just for him

Comment: And what should be written in the <Map marker?